# Using Elastic Search engine as a database

Tags: database, elasticsearch

When i first learnt about Elastic Search, some veteran's video/article/post suggested not to use it as a db store for persistence, but solely for indexing purposes. But nowadays, every other youtube video suggests ES as 1 of the dbs. Can someone throw light in detail for or against this, specially with some practical anecdotes?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: although you could use elasticsearch as primary nosql db, it's still a tool optimised for search and analytics, so for example not the best choice for use cases with frequent document updates

an important doc to review for evaluating pros and cons of this solution is the Elasticsearch Resiliency Status: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html (you definitely want to have a good understanding of what is guaranteed and what is not in terms of data loss)